# Residue fields of the closed points in $Spec(\mathbb{R}[X,Y])$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, quotient-spaces, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> What are the residue fields of the closed points in $Spec(\mathbb{R}[X,Y])$?

After finding the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$, which are of the form:

1. $\langle X-a,Y-b \rangle$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$
2. $\langle X-a,(Y-b)(Y-\overline{b}) \rangle$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$
3. $\langle (X-a)(X-\overline{a}),Y-(cX+d) \rangle$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ and $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $d+ca \in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$

I am trying to compute the quotients

1. $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{\langle X-a,Y-b \rangle}$
2. $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{\langle X-a,(Y-b)(Y-\overline{b}) \rangle}$
3. $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{\langle (X-a)(X-\overline{a}),Y-(cX+d) \rangle}$

Obviously, the quotient 1. is $\mathbb{R}$

For 2., I think $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{\langle X-a,(Y-b)(Y-\overline{b}) \rangle} \simeq \frac{\mathbb{R}[Y]}{\langle (Y-b)(Y-\overline{b}) \rangle} \simeq \mathbb{C}$

I need some help to compute 3.

Thanks!

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct.

Comment: 3) looks like $\mathbb{C}$, you're adjoining a root of an irreducible quadratic (to get $\mathbb{C}$) and then evaluating $\mathbb{C}[y]$ at $y=\text{something}$.  no matter what, a ring finitely generated over $\mathbb{R}$ that is also a field will be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ (nullstellensatz).